# How to write the events happening in controller to client var/log/messages in python?

Tags: python, controller, client

I am trying to write a code where Failover events happening on the filer side should also be logged on client /var/log/messages.

For example, I will be having the following
1. filers
2. n number of clients(Linux, windows)
3. test will be run using one RHEL host which can access filers and clients.
I tried using the logger for Linux with the -n option which specifies the client_ip followed by the message which needs to be logged to var/log/messages. I didn't get the output.

My Question is

1. can we use the logger functionality where we can specify the client IP to log the messages
2. if I can use logger then can I define the message as a variable and when the event happens can I call the logger as messages have to be updated runtime.